# Excel Function which will round up pricing of products to end with 9.00 (The cents should be .00)

Tags: excel-formula

I have this function which will round up or down and end the price with a 9. The cents should always be .00

It works correctly except for when column K has a price with a decimal for the cents. I did make the formatting for decimals to 0 but it doesn't work. If I click on certain prices for example 367 it would be 376.5 in the top section and my function would make it 365.5

```
=IF(K2>=5,ROUND(K2,(LEN(K2)-1)-LEN(INT(K2)))-1,0)
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Formatting only changes the display, the value remains the same

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to remove it in a function before the if statement? I need to add the formula to an ERP system which will pull pricing and then round everything up.

Comment: Generally one uses another (hidden) column to hold an intermediate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
=IF(K2>=5,ROUND(K2,-1)-1,0)
```

should do the trick, -1 in ROUND() means rounding to tens.